# JPQL query with "sum" aggregation is not working as expected

Tags: java, jpa, sum, jpql

I have the following ERD:

[image]

I want to select the sum of employee salary group by region, but my select statement does't work as expected.

Here is the code for this query:

```
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Salary findByRegion(String region) {
    return (Employee)  getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("select sum(e.employeeJob.salary) from Employee e where "
                    + "e.employeeDepartment.departmentLocation.locationCountry.countryRegion = :region")

            .setParameter("region", "%" + region + "%")
            .getSingleResult();
}
```

What am I doing wrong with that?

Comment: What persistence framework are you using?  JPA, other? Please add a tag to make that clear.  Also, please be clear about what you mean when you say *it doesn't work*.  That's a very vague statement.  Do you get an error?  Do you get incorrect results?  If so, which error, or which results do you get, and what are your expected results?

Comment: Yes, I use jpa. The salary is a part of another table,so that statement just did not return anything when I run it. Beside I add this select statement in the employeeDao class.I'm not sure that I can leave it there or have to create another Dao class

Comment: e.employeeJob.salary ?? I didn't see salary field in Job object. I only see minSalary and maxSalary in job object.

Comment: Yeah,you're right.Actually,that's maxSalary.I changed its name in the database

Comment: Because that statement is in emloyee Dao class so i have to put (employee) there.But I'm wondering that is it reason for returning the null data?

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons that your JPQL statement is not giving you expected results may be a missing field name of REGIONS entity at the end of your path expression: `e.employeeDepartment.departmentLocation.locationCountry.countryRegion` instead of `e.employeeDepartment.departmentLocation.locationCountry.countryRegion.region_name`

Answer (score -1):

You must use "**LIKE**" operator instead of "**=**" if you want to use "**%**". Change your code using this code below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Salary findByRegion(String region) {
return (Employee)  getEntityManager()
        .createQuery("select sum(e.employeeJob.salary) from Employee e where "
                + "e.employeeDepartment.departmentLocation.locationCountry.countryRegion LIKE :region")

        .setParameter("region", "%" + region + "%")
        .getSingleResult();
}
```